# Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.10 to dual boot with Windows 8, but every time I choose Ubuntu from grub menu, it always get stuck at this error and won't boot:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/920903aa-762f-40d2-8126-87f4b0e6f975 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.19.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.10.3-7ubuntu1.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a lost of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

I tried with `boot-repair`, but it doesn't help, [here is the log generated it](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1570104/).

Comment: Not going to "waste" an answer just as if trying hard fishing for rep points. The following +50 answer may already get some of you guys you out of your misery: http://askubuntu.com/questions/361886/cannot-find-root-device-after-latest-kernel-upgrade/363345 For those with "exotic" hardware, note the 6th pitfall, which I've just added recently to Braiam's great post. (i e. either missing `linux-image-extra`, or it got "destroyed" when upgrading kernel)

Comment: @syntaxerror That's what helped me. Thanks! For some reason, my issue with my system failing to find the NVMe root device, but only when VMD controller was enabled; but a different issue if it was disable.

Answer (score 58):

I had the very same problem. Thing is that I had the laptop off for long time and when I switched it on it showed the same message. Apparently some configurations changed (most likely to a default setting) with the machine off for long time.

I solved it following this link here on Stack Exchange:

["initramfs" error on boot ONLY on Dell XPS 13 (boots fine on other computer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028561/initramfs-error-on-boot-only-on-dell-xps-13-boots-fine-on-other-computer)

Solution is:

- Reboot.
- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> and go to the BIOS settings.
- System Configurations → SATA Operations
- Change RAID to AHCI

Comment: Worked on my Dell XPS15 9560. Thank you!

Comment: THANK YOU! You just saved me :)

Comment: A recent bios update changed this option and I was freaking out until I tried this. Thanks sooo much!

Comment: My only problem is then that windows will now not boot

Comment: Totally solved it for me after a BIOS update caused all of my settings to be lost. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect!!! its works 

Comment: Worked on a Dell XPS 13 7390, running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Apparently it switched to RAID upon very low power, by itself (well there was a yellow, Support Assist warning screen I had to click "Continue" through, but still). Running Ubuntu from a flash drive on the machine didn't even show any other drives on it so I was really worried but this fixed everything perfectly.

Comment: Worked on XPS 9560 as well, after leaving it off for a long time it didn't boot and this was the reason. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me again!

Comment: Also works for XPS 15 9550, also left it off for a long time. Thank you!

Comment: Life saver answer. THANKS!

Comment: Worked on my Dell XPS 15 9570 running Ubuntu 20.04.05. Thank you!

Comment: @LucaSteeb, I have the same issue; please help. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=6441354#post6441354

Comment: If i switch to AHCI my windows gives me a blue screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you installed [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) onto a partition/hard drive which is part of a RAID array, or an encrypted disk, or on Windows ME, it will likely fail to boot. **Installing Ubuntu Desktop onto one of these sources is [not supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Unsupported_set-ups)**.

If you *have* installed Ubuntu Desktop to one of the above sources, and it won't boot:

1. Uninstall Ubuntu.
2. Install Ubuntu to a hard drive or partition which is **not** part of a RAID array, not encrypted, and not on Windows ME, and it should boot up just fine.

Comment: Why do you assume this is Wubi on RAID?

Comment: hes probably not assuming, just telling you not to.

Comment: That link *doesn't* say you can't use RAID ... It says you can't use *software* RAID!  Hardware RAID is absolutely supported.

Answer (score 2):

I also occurred same problem but I can solve it using following link

http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/ubuntu-system-boot-problem/

**Attempt #1**

First, I tried to change rootdelay as error message said. I opened file /etc/default/grub
I found there the following line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
and changed it to:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootdelay=90 quiet splash"
rootdelay became longer, but unfortunately it didn’t fix the problem in my case.

**Attempt #2**

I edited /etc/fstab file. I executed the following command in terminal: sudo gedit /etc/fstab and edited fstab file in gedit. In the beginning my file looked like that:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=96889309-5f73-4688-8354-e64cd1bb158f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=480cc3f7-a39d-4d0f-93d5-49fc8df1a392 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Then, I commented one line and added another one describing /dev/sda1 disk device. Now, my file looks as follows:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=/dev/sda1  /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# UUID=96889309-5f73-4688-8354-e64cd1bb158f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=480cc3f7-a39d-4d0f-93d5-49fc8df1a392 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Problem still existed, so I tried another attempt to solve it.

**Attempt #3**

I opened terminal and typed the following command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

and then I typed another command to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After all of this, I rebooted computer and finally, error disappeared and problem was fixed!

Comment: How were you able to open the terminal :|

Answer (score 0):

I have got same issue while i'm doing patched for entire system which includes kernel. unfortunately package broken which leads kernel was partially upgrade and corrected.

I was scared about issue since where mail server was hosted and data also reside in the same machine.

I google it. tried all possible concepts as below.

```
1. Booting with live cd
2. doing fsck for / partition and /boot
3. grub-install on /dev/sda(which is default root filesystem)
4. check fstab
```

And following solve make happy to get boot server.

--> note in my case boot is mounted on /boot which is /dev/sda3 where as /dev/sda1
        / file system.

Simple solution to fix the issue(but to cross all module which are install on        kernel level

1. copy /boot of other server complete /boot excluding **grub.cfg** to   external flash disk
2. boot with live cd
3. find out root file system with following command
    **fdisk -l /dev/sda**
4. mount / file system on /mnt
   **mount /dev/sdXY /mnt**
5. mkdir directory to mount external data
    **mkdir -p  /mnt/pd**
6. mount flash disk data to /mnt/pd
7. now it is time to do chages on root file system with chroot command(Please care while doing chages)
8. **chroot /mnt**
9. now copy of entire /mnt/pd/boot/ to /mnt
10. **exit**
11. now unmout /mnt/pd
12. create new folder **mkdir -p /mnt/test**
13. mount /boot on /mnt/test

    **mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/test**
14. now /boot is mounted on /mnt/test/
15. again do **chroot /mnt**
16. rename all  file which contains /mnt/test/
17. now copy /mnt/boot (which we have copied from pd) to /mnt/test/
18. make sure your using original grub.cfg /mnt/test/boot/grub/**grub.cfg**
19. **exit**
20. **reboot**
21. you will be successfully boot to the server without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

I just randomly started typing stuff... try:

```
(initramfs) blkid
(initramfs) blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sda
(initramfs) blkid
(initramfs) exit
```

This at least gets you to the desktop where you can begin trouble shooting your problem which is probably due to a proprietary driver or something

Comment: blkid was GOD in `initramfs`! `ls -l` in GRUB (Grand Universal Bootloader)

Comment: can you please explain us what this does?

Answer (score -1):

After much effort I finally made it:

I booted live from usb to fix the problem where i found that update-grub failed with an error "couldnt find canonical path in cow..."

I then tried alot until I found this:

https://askubuntu.com/a/772892/925082

where I followed the second way but replacing his sda5 with my sdb6 as root