# Gave up waiting for root device

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 but cannot fully boot. Here is my error message:

```
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
  ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/8ABA9BB9BA9BA06D does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!


BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands.`

(initramfs) _
```

I'm a beginner and don't have any idea what to do next. This is for a desktop pc with the following:

- Windows Vista Home Premium
- Intel Core 2 Duo 6600 @ 2.4GHz
- 2 GB RAM
- 32 bit OS
- Nvidia GeForce 8800 GTS video card
- Hard Drive: Nvidia Stripe 465.77 GB on nForce RAID controller

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I reviewed that answer but don't think it applies.  I don't know what a RAID array is and don't know how to check if my hard drive is encrypted.  I suspect it's not encrypted because the computer is 6 years old and I never recall asking for an encrypted hard drive.  This installation is just for one computer.  I have one hard drive (C:/).

Comment: Does it boot correctly from a 12.04 live CD? That will verify most of your hardware and also act as a tool for fixing things later.

Comment: Exact the same error message as in this old post: http://askubuntu.com/q/504383/367990 Even the UUID is totally identical!