# Gave Up Waiting For Root Device - Fresh Install 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, initramfs

I am getting the error:

```
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
  ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/8ABA9BB9BA9BA06D does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!


BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands.`

(initramfs) _
```

I have attempted many of the solutions provided in the other copies of this question but I have an additional complication which prevents me from performing the most common solutions. I can not type commands in the initramfs prompt. My keyboard works fine for grub but once I get to this prompt pressing keys produces no results.

Comment: The UUID 8ABA9BB9BA9BA06D cannot be valid!

Comment: This newer post is about exactly the same error message: http://askubuntu.com/q/442066/367990 Even the UUID is totally identical!

Comment: what about a different keyboard?

Comment: I fixed the problem by installing arch

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix/repair your boot partition

Follow this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/742130/214264