# New Ubuntu install, initramfs

Tags: boot, usb, initramfs

I've only really used Debian and Debian variants before and then only on either a virtual box or raspberry Pi.
I'm trying to install the server variant of Ubuntu onto a Samsung N150 plus netbook (1GB ram, 150GB HDD)

In the install for some reason it wouldn't install GRUB it just said fatal error so I installed LILO (version 24 I think) but after that the install completed successfully.
As I have a another windows PC, I let it use the whole disk to install too.
On the first boot up it gives the following error:

```
[ 2.913376] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
-check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-check root= (did the system boot to the right device?)
-missing modules (cat /proc/modules; Is /dev)
ALERT! /dev/sdb1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
[ 33.370303] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[ 33.383562] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[ 33.387133] usbhid: USB HID core driver 

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) [ 41.000170] random: nonblocking pool is initialised
```

After that there was a pause (maybe 30 mins) just as I finished typing out the above it added two more lines on below:

```
[ 1292.492081] perf samples too long (2501 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[ 1292.492081] INFO: NMI handler (perf_event_nmi_handler) too long to run: 3.302 msecs
(initramfs)
```

I've tried googling the problem but most of the time it doesn't seem to happen on first boot very often. Most of the solutions involve changing code on a 'live cd.' I installed from a pen drive and when I boot from that the option is to run the install again but I don't see anywhere to access the terminal.

Any help would be much apprechiated!

Comment: To access the terminal from the live USB, choose 'try Ubuntu' instead of 'install Ubuntu'.

Comment: "As I have a another windows PC, I let it use the whole disk to install too. On the first boot up it gives the following error: " Can you elaborate on what do you mean by saying this?

Comment: There is no option for try instead of install. It first asks language choice and then into the install.

Comment: @PauliusŠukys Previously I had windows 7 installed on the netbook but I have another desktop with windows on it so I didn't want to dual boot the netbook. In the Ubuntu install it asks where you want to install it and I selected the option to use the full disk rather than create a partition

Comment: As an update to this, I did manage to use the repair future to install GRUB but that just loads a black screen with the word grub in it. I tried entering the command 'boot' and it says 'you need to load the Kernel first'

Comment: The error here I think was in the software I used to load the OS to the pen drive. I tried a different piece of software to do it (after formatting the drive) and everything worked fine. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a live USB and boot your system.

Make sure you can mount your main partition in which your Ubuntu is installed. Lets assume it is /dev/sda1

Unmount that partition (NECESSARY). Now run this command which will fix errors in partition:

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sda1
```

Make sure you you can mount the partition. Restart your system. it should work now.

(I faced with this problem today, I did exactly same thing and problem solved)