# 14.04 Gave up waiting for root device

Tags: 14.04, boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus PC.  (If it matters, the OS is installed on my SSD.)  The attach image shows the error message when booting.  [Picture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUr87.jpg)

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  — Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    — Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    — Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  — Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/aa91b9fe-eea9-4578-a707-ob9d585761e9 does not exist.   
Dropping to a shell! 

BusyBox v.1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.1-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)   
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs)
```

I have found a temporary solution for start up or restart.  After the error message is completely on the screen, I type **blkid** > **blockdev** > **blkid** > **exit**.  I have no idea what "blkid" or "blockdev" are, but my PC finishes booting.  Temp. solution not from me: https://askubuntu.com/a/268420/530393

I recently have found a potential permanent solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/742130/530393, but I don't fully understand the steps.  Could I do this from the Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the steps in the answer can be done from a terminal.

The first thing you need to do is determine what partition you installed Ubuntu on. This can be done by using

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It will probably be /dev/sda1 but look at the descriptions to the right when it lists the devices. Next, you need to unmount the device. This is done with

```
sudo umount name_of_device
```

If it complains that the device is busy, try

```
sudo umount -f name_of_device
```

Then run the fsck command in the answer.

Comment: The partition is **/dev/sdb1**.  What/where is the name of device?  

Would you know what I can do if my CD/DVD drive does not show up under **sudo lsblk -f**?

Comment: I unmount the partition?  **sudo umount /dev/sdb1**?

Comment: I unmounted the partition.  Then, my computer did a restart by itself.  After that, my computer login didn't work.  I reinstalled Ubuntu.  Now there is no booting error.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes a reinstall is just the easiest way to fix a problem. Good job.