# Start-up error: ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a serious problem with Ubuntu 14.04. When I start my computer it shows the following errors:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  — Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    — Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    — Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  — Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist.   
Dropping to a shell! 

BusyBox v.1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu11) built-in shell (ash)   
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs)
```

I got this error earlier but it fixed automatically, but this it keeps saying this errors. Please please help me.

---

**Update from Comments below**

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sda1 :Label="backu" uuid="c4406f0a406fo312" Type = "ntfs" 
/dev/sda3 : Label="linux"c6e7b2c6-5e8f-4a2d-b666-9489ef7c7c8f" Type = "ext4" 
/dev/sda5: uuid="6e0361c9-bbb6-4395-a75e-ef8d645245d0" Type = "ext4" 
/dev/sda6: uuid="740f28da-723a-40d3-995b-3d5dc0d30120" Type = "ext4" 
/dev/sda7: uuid="30c1ba3b-dd3e-4ec2-989b-2e3a3d0d30d8067" Type = "ext4" 
/dev/sda8: uuid="06145b6-0538-4a4b-b424-a5f7a732e8e1" Type = "swap"
```

Comment: what is your device node name? /dev/sdaX?

Comment: do a `blkid` from command line (from a live dvd if needed) and check the UUID's against what /etc/fstab has.Or post both results into your question please.

Comment: Rinzwind i dont understand what u telling to do? Please elaborate on.

Comment: Boot from Ubuntu live disk, click on try Ubuntu option on startup. Openup the terminal(ctrl+alt+t) and then run `sudo blkid` command on it. Finally post it's output on your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu)

Comment: /dev/sda1 :Label="backu" uuid="c4406f0a406fo312" Type = "ntfs"
/dev/sda3 : Label="linux"c6e7b2c6-5e8f-4a2d-b666-9489ef7c7c8f" Type = "ext4"

/dev/sda5: uuid="6e0361c9-bbb6-4395-a75e-ef8d645245d0" Type = "ext4"
/dev/sda6: uuid="740f28da-723a-40d3-995b-3d5dc0d30120" Type = "ext4"
/dev/sda7: uuid="30c1ba3b-dd3e-4ec2-989b-2e3a3d0d30d8067" Type = "ext4"
/dev/sda8: uuid="06145b6-0538-4a4b-b424-a5f7a732e8e1" Type = "swap"

please help me guyz im in so much trouble ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)

Comment: @user258548 I suggest that you do a `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-extra` (also works as regular user). What do you see in first column? Usually you'd see `ii` (very good) or `rc` (not good). Because `rc` means the extra modules are not correctly installed (or something went wrong during their installation). __Not all__ people need this, but imagine you're booting off a disk at an external hardware controller (PCI/PCIe...), this will normally not be supported by the "basic" kernel image but require additional modules (or call them drivers) to work. In Ubuntu, most of these are in `extra`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment (due to my reputation), so it looks like I have to write an answer...
I had this problem a few days ago, but it was because I restored an image (clonezilla) on a new partition, and, each time you create the partition (I don't know ,maybe also when you format it), it gets a new UUID, a different one from the one stored in the image content.
In any case: look for that UUID (the one you put with xxxx) in /boot/grub/grub.cfg and /boot/grub/i386-pc/load.cfg and correct it properly... BUT, in case you recreate the partition (that was my case), DO NOT change the UUID on those files, it's better to change the new UUID of the partition for the previous one it had with:
tune2fs /dev/{device} -U {uuid}

Comment: If this is supposed to be a comment (it could be an answer but only sort of), you should wait until you have sufficient reputation, not post an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for a while. Recently I decided to verify checksum for the distributive (I found some mention of that in other problem solution). But md5 was correct.

What finally helped me, was clearing my kubuntu live cd flash and creating new one with unetbootin. 10 minutes for fresh install and everything is up and running.

So my suggestion is do a foolproof check before any other investigation.
I hadn't done it before just because Try Kubuntu worked absolutely fine from my flash drive. And I got through installation without any issues/errors/warnings.