# ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, boot-repair, initramfs

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

I ran in terminal `sudo apt-get update`. Then I rebooted the system. And now I see:

```
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell
initramfs:_
```

I can't boot up LIVE Ubuntu from USB flash drive. Yes, I double checked BIOS setup and the USB flash drive is OK and runs on another machine. Right now I am going to buy a  DVD and burn a Live DVD from another laptop.

`sudo blkid` gives me:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"  
/dev/sda1: UUID="xxxx" TYPE="ext4"   
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS i386" TYPE="iso960"
```

`/etc/fstab` has the same `UUID="xxxx"` and there is a line with:

```
errors=remount-ro 0
```

I tried using boot-repair but I still can't log in to Ubuntu.

I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu, because I have a lot of data there.

Do you have any advice how this can be solved?

Comment: Run `sudo blkid` from the terminal (from a live DVD if needed) and check the UUID's against what `/etc/fstab` has. Or post both results into your question please. How to run `sudo blkid` from a live DVD: Boot from Ubuntu live disk, click on *Try Ubuntu* option on startup. Open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and then run `sudo blkid` command in it. Finally, post its output in your question.

Comment: ok @karel `sudo blkid` gives me

`/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 

/dev/sda1: UUID="xxxx" TYPE="ext4"

dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS i386" TYPE="iso960"` 

/etc/fstab have the same UUID="xxxx"

and there is line where is written errors=remount-ro 0 –

Comment: I have this after run boot-repair
[Boot-repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8150006/)

Comment: and then still I cant log in to ubuntu...

Comment: sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.020.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sda1:clean, 491701/19054592 files, 27163705/76189184 blocks

Comment: I dont know how to write is these askubuntu add comment window, even when read lear more ....

Comment: @MarcinGorski please add your solution as an answer and mark it accepted instead of editing the question.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kilXfY-k_9A It solved me the problem

Answer (score 30):

Solution was to perform these commands from liveDVD, it allows me to do things on my sda1 from that liveDVD(as far I understand)

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
reboot
```

A friend of mine from ubuntu pl forum [helped me solve](http://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=133&t=175292&p=993631#p993631) this problem.

He found out that there might be error in initramfs, which should be updated as part of the kernel update. If anything goes wrong during that update problems like mine could happen.

Comment: Good post.  I would like to add that Ubuntu isn't necessarily installed on `sda1`.  To help determine where it is installed run `sudo fdisk -l`.  Assuming you know what hard drive you installed Ubuntu to then that command should help you determine which sd* maps to that drive.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu MATE 17.04 (New Install), and it didn't help unfortunately...

Comment: I was getting `WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic` because LiveCD had different kernel version. So I've mounted `tmp`, `lib` and `lib64` and then everything worked.

Comment: I had to specify the filesystem to mount for an ext4 partition (`mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt`), otherwise this worked great.

Answer (score -1):

People may frown on this if they want, but I have found that using "`/dev/sdX`" works more reliably for me than UUID for my personal systems. In an enterprise environment, I would put more effort into making it work with the UUID instead of the "/dev/" address, but you should be safe using `/dev/sdaX` in `/etc/fstab` instead of UUID reference, at least to be able to boot your system while you continue to search for the answer to why exactly the boot is failing in spite of having the correct UUID in /etc/fstab.

If you wish to go this route, use the following procedure:

1. Boot into recovery shell or boot into a live USB drive or CD
2. Mount your system partition that is failing to boot
3. Edit the `/etc/fstab` file in the system partition mentioned in Step 2 as root and replace `UUID=XXXXX` with the corresponding `/dev/sdX` label in all of the relevant `/etc/fstab` entries.

Note: This procedure is known to me to be reliable for Ubuntu and Ubuntu-derived distributions (as of the writing of this article; this could easily change with any upcoming release). I know for a fact that it won't work reliably for some other distributions such as knoppix or Arch Linux (this is due to differences in the way that UDEV scans in devices and gives them names in the /dev filesystem). If you are using a non-Ubuntu-derived distribution, please do not use this method or else use it at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MGodby but I already find solution.

Comment: Your method is the old method, which was replaced for fairly good reasons, mainly that the drive numbering is not constant, and it's possible to boot from an unexpected drive.  This is not possible with UUID.  But I often use the "LABEL=___" format, just because it's clearer to see right away what's what.  Example: `LABEL=data_partition`.