# ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell HP Desktop

Tags: 14.04, boot, mount

I'm in a situation similar to the one described in this post
[ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)

I have 2 internal hard drives. The original Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation booted from `/dev/sdb2`, using `/dev/sdb1` as swap.

I tried a clean installation on `/dev/sda2` from an USB stick and booting it gave me the same issue.

Booting from `/dev/sda3` (the original windows 7 recovery partition) works perfectly.

Booting from the USB stick, the filesystems on `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2` look OK.

Obviously I tried the suggested procedures on `/dev/sdb2` and on `/dev/sda2` but with no result.

Comment: So what does your fstab contain now? UID or sdX?

Comment: UUID anyway i asked on ubuntuforums also, and i got a suggestion to run grub-install instead of updating, and strangely that did the trick, the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

I tried the procedure [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/a/516471/527764) but nothing changed. I then got a suggestion of running `grub-install` instead of `update-grub` after `update-initramfs` and that mysteriously did the trick.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa: that's what he did: he got an answer on Ubuntuforums and then posted it here!  ;-)