# /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXX does not exist dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, raid, busybox

I have just installed ubuntu 14.04 and when I reboot and remove the media I get the

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 -check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT ! /Dev/disk/by-uuid/e9399244-24c6-46bd-9786-051806f0f93f does not exist. Dropping to a shell

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 10 E411-5D60 -> ../../sda1  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 10 e9399244-24c6-46bd-9786-051806f0f93f -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 10 df7a3fc6-d2dc-4c85-a445-8bbc02ff7c84 -> ../../sdb5
```

and I tried the solution found here:
[Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)
twice...I still get the busybox shell...what can I do from here?

Comment: The boot procedure tries to boot from disk e9399244- etc, but cannot find it. Either your root disk (the one you installed Ubuntu on) is defective, or it has taken on a new identifier string after installation. To see what disks are in /dev/disk/by-uuid and what they point to (/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 etc.), please enter `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` and paste the output in your question.

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 10 E411-5D60 -> ../../sda1  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 10 e9399244-24c6-46bd-9786-051806f0f93f -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 10 df7a3fc6-d2dc-4c85-a445-8bbc02ff7c84 -> ../../sdb5

Comment: So you installed Ubuntu on sdb1; sda1 is a FAT partition, that can't be a Linux partition. Is sdb a disk that has since been removed, by any chance? You may need to look around in /dev/disk/by-id/ to see if you can find the vendor's name of the disk.

Comment: I'm thinking sda1 is the livecd usb stick. the top part is what it boots to after I finish the install. If I type exit at the initramfs prompt. It successfully boots to Linux.

Comment: Try this answer.http://askubuntu.com/a/516471/146791

Comment: That did not work as well.   If I type exit at teh initramfs prompt, the boot process continues. So is there a way to have a startup script that just issues the exit command?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a knowledgeable Linux user but this may be helpful. I have a dual boot PC running Windows 7 Pro and Ubuntu 14.04. The problem described arose this year after an Ubuntu update and Grub reconfiguration. After restart and selecting Ubuntu from the Grub menu very similar screen message appeared after initially running the Plymouth startup screen.
At the '(initramfs)' prompt the system stopped. after waiting several minutes, I typed:
Exit 
After about 1 minute the startup recommenced without problem.
I have experienced the same problem after later Ubuntu updates and Grub reconfiguration but this method always works.
After Ubuntu has been rebooted once or twice without further updates, the problem disappears.

Comment: I have experience this too.  Took me 3 reboots though.