# Unable to boot into ubuntu 15.04 after a clean install

Tags: boot, 15.04

I have an older samsung laptop running dual core amd with 4 gigs ram, 
And I was previously running windows , due to severe lagging I installed ubuntu and now I am unable to boot up

It keeps showing

```
ACPI PCC probe failed
Starting version 219
Ata2:soft reset failed (1st FIS failed) 
Alert /dev/disk/by-uuid/612a3bcc-0033-47bf-bcca-b6ad3a4224c8 does not exist..dropping to shell
```

And then it's says the the devices taking too long

Comment: Please look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell . It looks like the same issue answered there.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like it can't detect your disk. You could try reinstalling if only some random bug hadn't happened, or type `lsblk` and see how are your disks/partitions named, from the install you can know, that if your disk is for example sda, than the first partition(typically ext3/ext4) will be sda1 and the second will be swap ... although I find this order not very logical. Now you know the disk where you installed is called sda1 so you go edit the file /etc/fstab and in the line containing this name `/dev/disk/by-uuid/612a3bcc-0033-47bf-bcca-b6ad3a4224c8` you rename it to `/dev/XXXY` in this cas XXXY == sda1.

Hope it helps **:)**

Comment: Yeah and after editing dont firget to run as root:
`update-initramfs -u;
update-grub;
reboot`

Comment: could i get a bit more help , i dont see /dev/disk/ in fstab

Comment: I mean /dev/<disk> .... disks are usually named something like sda/hda... show me a `ls -la` and I`ll tell you