# ALERT! /dev/mapper/xxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on vmware.  I can't login to Ubuntu.

i'm in a situation similar to the one described in this post [ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell?newreg=ff900ea51e50467c9555c3292ce347c6)

I have tried the solution of the above post but on this command

```
 update-initramfs -u
```

I get this error

```
depmod error could not open directory lib/modules/3.16.0-44-generic
```

```
ls /lib
```

[image: This is the content of the directory lib]

Do you have any advice how this can be solved?

Comment: Which kernel do you have installed? Please add the output of `uname -r`. If the output deviates from the kernel version in the error message, try `update-initramfs -uk $(uname -r)` and then select the kernel with this version on the next boot.

Comment: @the_Seppi With uname -r I get 3.19.0-25-generic. Running update-initramfs -uk $(uname -r) I get the same error written above but on lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic

Comment: Oh I just noticed that this won't work... `uname -r` in a chroot environment gives the kernel version of the chroot host... Fot what kernel versions do directories exist in `/lib/modules`?

Comment: @the_Seppi I have added the content of the directory lib in my question. Seems that the directory modules there isn't.

Comment: Try `apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-3.16.0-44-generic`

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini `could not resolve it.archive.ubuntu.com`. Maybe a dns error?

Comment: make sure that `/etc/resolv.conf` in the chroot matches the one of the host

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini `error writing resolv.conf no such file or directory`. But with `ls` I can see the file in the directory

Comment: how are you writing to the file?

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini  `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: oh, that's because `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink (a broken symlink in your case). Remove it before editing

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini perfect. Now I have edited the file writing `nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4`. But I get the same error: `could not resolve it.archive.ubuntu.com`. What's wrong?