# Will Not Boot After 14.04 Upgrade

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, boot, grub2

After upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04, I am receiving the error listed below. I would rather not reinstall if possible. I've tried boot repair and several manual methods to fix it with no success. I have the results of my boot repair on pastebin in the URL listed below. Does anyone have a possible solution? Thanks.

Pastern (/etc/fstab is commented, but I tried using either of the entries without comments):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23568032/

Error when booting up:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  — Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    — Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    — Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  — Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/17d1276b-5f5d-4ca9-8999-efd0c73f5177 does not exist.   
Dropping to a shell! 

BusyBox v.1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8.1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)   
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs)
```

Comment: The boot error is about a partition that can't be found, and your Fstab is (almost) entirely commented out. Try uncommenting both the lines that start with `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Otherwise, try the solutions here: [ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](http://askubuntu.com/q/516217/301745)