# Dropped to a BusyBox shell on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, gnome, usb, initramfs

I think I'm about to go insane.

I currently have a 128GB USB stick with an Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS installation on it. I use it on a laptop with Windows 10 installed, and I boot to the drive whenever I want to use Linux.

It works fine for a couple of hours until GNOME drops me to a BusyBox shell with initramfs. I've tried solving it by booting to the recovery mode whilst having it plugged into a VM in Virtualbox and runing `fsck`. But, when I plug it back into my laptop it still drops me to the damn BusyBox shell. I've tried adding `rootdelay=90` to `/etc/default/grub`, and I've tried to mount the drive and update initramfs and gnome whilst in a live cd (for reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/516471/652265), but it still drops me to the shell. What should I do?

The USB stick btw is a Sandisk Ultra Fit 128GB USB 3.0 stick

Comment: Did the fsck produce any errors?   What were you doing before problems startred -- like an update doing lots of IO? I've had one of the USB buttons die in the middle of an update (overheated I guess), but pulling it apart, the micro SD card memory was fine.

Comment: @ubanf1 Just did a regular apt-get update and upgrade. The USB drive btw is quite prone to overheating, might have something to do with that...

Comment: Update: Tried to use a male to female USB cable with the USB drive when connecting it to my laptop and it worked! No BusyBox console. The laptop I'm running it on has USB 2.0 ports, and so does the cable, whilst the drive uses USB 3.0. Why does this work?

Comment: USB3 is backwards compatible with USB2.  You problem seems to be a mechanical one with the contacts if just adding a cable fixed it.