# I'm trying to disable RST so I can install ubuntu alongside win10, but win10 keeps reverting my changes. What can I do?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, intel, ahci

When using this official guide (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347), windows reverts my changes once I reboot.

I have also tried the following, which I have seen on multiple sites:

```
Click the Start Button and type cmd
Right-click the result and select Run as administrator
Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal (ALT: bcdedit /set safeboot minimal)
Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup
Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID
Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot (ALT: bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot)
Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.
```

(source for this particular copypaste: https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci)

However, when I reboot after turning off safe boot, win10 reverts to using RSI, taking the UEFI with it.

I am using a new Medion Erazer P17613, secure boot/fast startup are turned off.
I plan Ubuntu to be my primary os and to only have to boot into windows if I need it for uni work and can't get it to work in virtualbox, so a solution which involves me having to go into UEFI to switch os would be workable, although not optimal.

edit: I don't know why askubuntu keeps telling me it's a duplicate, because the question it's referring to does NOT have it constantly revert, which I put in the title and the first paragraph...

Anyway. Uni's started, so I don't have any more time. I'm nuking Windows and just running it in VM. this edit is mostly to explain why I won't be checking the thread any more. thanks anyway.

Editing again, because, um - it wasn't actually Windows all along. I had some issues with the installation (the third-party software bug) and then RST turned itself back on (?!)

so I was looking into secure boot again, found [this](https://techoverflow.net/2019/05/23/how-to-disable-secure-boot-on-insydeh20-uefi-bios-acer-aspire-a515-52-51el/), went to try it and noticed another secure boot option in the security tab which wasn't the one I had found previously, tried it out of curiosity, and it worked.

just for the record: I did not actually need to do the supervisor password thing. I don't know if it's only this one or also the other secure boot required to be turned off, but.

I apologise for my assumption that it was Windows causing the issue, that probably didn't help anything. for anyone else with this problem, the wording may not be as obvious as you think it should be (I'm incredibly literal) so search everything even slightly security-related.

edit again, trying to reinstall just to be sure, and RST is back on?!

v apologies for the below being slightly lengthy. I don't want to be the 'found a solution but didn't post it' person, and I'm typing this as I go.

edit for hopefully the final time: I got past the point where it would tell me RST is enabled by switching the boot order to boot from the USB before anything else, and also turned RST off again while I was in the bios at that point. this gave as little time as possible between disabling RST and installing from USB.

I ended up in initramfs having the problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001351/uuid-xxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell) because RST turned itself back on, but `reboot -f`, going to bios, and turning it off again let me boot. so that's what I'll be doing every time it boots I guess, but at least it works now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workaround to Install Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel RST systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems). It worked for me to use **Choice #2 in heynnema's answer**.

Comment: @sudodus choice 2 doesn't work as is, it's what I've already tried. I hadn't tried choice 1, so I tried it out; it caused a bsod, so I'm going to run a reset and see if it plays nicely this time.

Comment: update to above: choice 1 didn't work either. I tried choice 2 again, went into bios after turning off safe mode, and it had again reverted to RST.

Comment: Let us hope someone else can suggest a method that works in your computer.

Comment: if you reboot into Windows without first making it non-RST then it'll reset to RST.  That's a Windows change you have to do, and not Ubuntu.