# Boot failure: Gave up waiting for root file system device. UUID does not exist

Tags: 18.04, grub2, uefi, boot-repair, initramfs

**Edit 4:** I've reinstalled Ubuntu and erased the disk, now its working again and I learned my lesson on system backups. Thank you for your support nonetheless.

I've been stuck all day trying to get my custom-built Ubuntu 18 computer for a robotics application to boot again.

**Here is what happened:**
It has been disconnected from the internet for a month or so and I ran `sudo apt update && apt upgrade` where the second command led to a bunch of errors, I unfortunately did not document. Rerunning it failed as well and starting Firefox to google the problem showed that it is already running and cannot be opened again (although it was not running).
Therefore, I rebooted and was greeted with this: `/dev/sda4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.` I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/697197). Afterwards, I was able to boot again.
Then, I re-ran `sudo apt update && apt upgrade`, when it suggested to run `sudo apt autoremove`, which I did. The system then said, it required a restart which led me to the error mentioned in the title:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
 -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay=(did the system wait long enough?)
 -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=b80b71b0-f0c6-4532-963f-4b92db7137e1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell

BusyBox v1.27 2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

First of all, my keyboard is not working in this shell (initramfs), so I could only shutdown the computer with the on/off-button (by now I've tested another keyboard which won't work either). After a couple of desperate hard reboots, I still ended with the above view every time.

**What I tried:** After reading a lot of forum entries because I've got absolutely no idea about EFI, bootloaders, grub and all of this, I finally got my Ubuntu install USB stick and booted into it. Here, I tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/516471/1396220) and had a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001351/uuid-xxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell).  Furthermore, I installed and used [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Unfortunately, all to no avail.
**Edit:**  I forgot to mention that I already edited grub.cfg (In the GRUB menu, I pressed 'e' and replaced all instances of the UUID ...37e1 with /dev/sda4) but the problem remained. **Edit 3:** I also removed "ro" from the line containing "linux" which also did not solve the problem.
**Edit 2:** I tried to edit grub.cfg again from the GRUB menu and changed the UUID to d7851347-5b99-4bb5-adf9-47c49f33611a as suggested by ubfan1 in the comments. Well, didn't work either. But I've added some photos of the GRUB config and command line prompts at the bottom of this post.

**These are the results:**

- Using the live stick, I am able to see my SSD, mount and access it. All steps from this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/516471/1396220) executed without errors. But rebooting with unmounting the stick, led me to the same error as before.
- I had a look at my BIOS settings, but my SATA settings are configured for AHCI and boot options allow EFI and legacy options.
- Boot-repair was also unable to solve the problem. After executing it and rebooting, the problem persists. But below is the info generated by boot-repair.

**The computer:** The sytem is a rugged, custom-built computer for mobile robotics with a main board running an American Megatrends BIOS (Version 2.20.1271) and a single 1TB Samsung SSD 860. It has an Intel CoffeeLake i7-8700T processor and 64GB RAM as well as an NVIDIA graphic card (if this is of any relevance).

**The question:** Can someone please show me how to fix this error or point me in the right direction, so that I won't have to reinstall Ubuntu and configure the system all over again?

**Edit 3:** Here are the results from running 'sudo blkid' from the live stick:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="1429-CC00" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="e4bb4583-22c0-4bc6-a1fa-d1bb1b3f27a0"
/dev/sda4: UUID="b80b71b0-f0c6-4532-963f-4b92db7137e1" TYPE="ext4" PTUUID="d8a8d274" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="d7851347-5b99-4bb5-adf9-47c49f33611a"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda2: PTUUID="2f6ca792" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="e6e6ec4d-80d0-46b5-bc3d-28f9ccf59e16"
/dev/sda3: UUID="ff161f87-866c-44d3-8fc3-5a44f5263535" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="18d1b724-907d-49bc-bdaa-5d9708e843d7"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2020-02-03-18-40-13-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="6e037a9d" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="6e037a9d-01"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="D055-8513" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="6e037a9d-02"
```

**Here is the report from boot-repair:** (any advice on how to properly format it here is also appreciated):
*The results show my Samsung SSD (sda) and the live stick (sdb)*

> ```
> boot-repair-4ppa130                                              [20210818_1128]
>
> ============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================
>
>  => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
>     1050624 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found 
>     at this location.
>
> sda1: __________________________________________________________________________
>
>     File system:       vfat
>     Boot sector type:  FAT32
>     Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
>     Operating System:  
>     Boot files:        
>
> sda2: __________________________________________________________________________
>
>     File system:       BIOS Boot partition
>     Boot sector type:  -
>     Boot sector info: 
>
> sda3: __________________________________________________________________________
>
>     File system:       swap
>     Boot sector type:  -
>     Boot sector info: 
>
> sda4: __________________________________________________________________________
>
>     File system:       ext4
>     Boot sector type:  -
>     Boot sector info: 
>     Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
>     Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub
>
> sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________
>
>     File system:       iso9660
>     Boot sector type:  Unknown
>     Boot sector info: 
>     Operating System:  
>     Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg
>
>
> ================================ 1 OS detected =================================
>
> OS#1:   Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on sda4
>
> ============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================
>
> CPU architecture: 64-bit
> Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, bionic, x86_64)
>
>
> ===================================== UEFI =====================================
>
> BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
> SecureBoot disabled.
>
> efibootmgr -v
> BootCurrent: 0006
> Timeout: 1 seconds
> BootOrder: 0000,0006,0005,0004,0007
> Boot0000* ubuntu  HD(1,GPT,e4bb4583-22c0-4bc6-a1fa-d1bb1b3f27a0,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
> Boot0004* Hard Drive  BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.6.0. .P.R.O.
> ```
>
> .1.T.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.S.N.2.F.N.M.0.0.5.2.5.5.5.
> .Y. . . .
> ........BO..NO........s.T.O.S.H.I.B.A....................A.......................F..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.0.2.2.C.F.F.6.B.8.A.6.C.3.5.1.E.2.5.C.D.3.D.4........BO
> Boot0005* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell    VenMedia(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664c8012)..BO
> Boot0006* UEFI: TOSHIBA   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(4,0)/CDROM(1,0x2eec,0x4d00)..BO
> Boot0007* UEFI: TOSHIBA, Partition 2  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(4,0)/HD(2,MBR,0x6e037a9d,0x2eec,0x1340)..BO
> This session has been detected as 'live' because /proc/cmdline contains (boot=casper)
> This session has been detected as 'live' because df -Th / contains overlay
>
> ```
> 78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
> 78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
> 2895d47544fd587b26c7e29be1295c27   sda1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
> 621356d82b109cd860ad92cdf241c58b   sda1/BOOT/grubx64.efi
> 82894bcbe4f010664226ba7591372538   sda1/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
> 621356d82b109cd860ad92cdf241c58b   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
> dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
> 78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
>
>
> ============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================
>
> Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________
>
> sda   : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
>
> Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________
>
> sda1  : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
> sda4  : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
>
> Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________
>
> sda1  : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
> sda4  : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
>
> Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________
>
> sda1  : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
> sda4  : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
>
> fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________
>
> Disk sda: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
> Disk identifier: 33BF281B-620C-4EE0-9E23-F71A72F15DE5
>            Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
> sda1        2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
> sda2     1050624    1052671       2048     1M BIOS boot
> sda3  1998407680 2000408575    2000896   977M Linux swap
> sda4     1052672 1998407679 1997355008 952.4G Linux filesystem
> Partition table entries are not in disk order.
> Disk sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15518924800 bytes, 30310400 sectors
> Disk identifier: 0x6e037a9d
>       Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
> sdb1  *        0 4153407 4153408    2G  0 Empty
> sdb2       12012   16939    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
>
> parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________
>
> sda:1024GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA Samsung SSD 860:;
> 1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
> 2:538MB:539MB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
> 4:539MB:1023GB:1023GB:ext4::;
> 3:1023GB:1024GB:1024MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
> sdb:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:TOSHIBA TransMemory:;
>
> blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________
>
> NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
> sda                                                                                                                
> ├─sda1 vfat     1429-CC00                            e4bb4583-22c0-4bc6-a1fa-d1bb1b3f27a0                          EFI
> ```
>
> System Partition
> ├─sda2                                               e6e6ec4d-80d0-46b5-bc3d-28f9ccf59e16
> ├─sda3 swap     ff161f87-866c-44d3-8fc3-5a44f5263535 18d1b724-907d-49bc-bdaa-5d9708e843d7
> └─sda4 ext4     b80b71b0-f0c6-4532-963f-4b92db7137e1 d7851347-5b99-4bb5-adf9-47c49f33611a
> sdb    iso9660  2020-02-03-18-40-13-00                                                    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS amd64
> ├─sdb1 iso9660  2020-02-03-18-40-13-00               6e037a9d-01                          Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS amd64
> └─sdb2 vfat     D055-8513                            6e037a9d-02                          Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS amd64
>
> ```
> df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________
>
>         Avail Use% Mounted on
> sda1   501.4M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
> sda4     861G   3% /mnt
> sdb         0 100% /cdrom
>
> Mount options: __________________________________________________________________
>
> sda1   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
> sda4   rw,relatime
> sdb    ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048
>
> ====================== sda4/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================
>
> Ubuntu   b80b71b0-f0c6-4532-963f-4b92db7137e1
> Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-81-generic   b80b71b0-f0c6-4532-963f-4b92db7137e1
> Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-77-generic   b80b71b0-f0c6-4532-963f-4b92db7137e1
> Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-154-generic   b80b71b0-f0c6-4532-963f-4b92db7137e1
> ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
> System setup   uefi-firmware
> ### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
>
> ========================== sda4/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================
>
> # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
> # / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
> UUID=b80b71b0-f0c6-4532-963f-4b92db7137e1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
> /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
> UUID=1429-CC00  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
>
> ======================= sda4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================
>
> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
> GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
>
> ==================== sda4: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================
>
>            GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
>  322.627021790 = 346.418126848  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
>    5.173885345 = 5.555417088    boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-154-generic                1
>    6.823253632 = 7.326412800    boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-77-generic                  2
>  698.909198761 = 750.448037888  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-81-generic                  1
>    5.173885345 = 5.555417088    vmlinuz                                        1
>  698.909198761 = 750.448037888  vmlinuz.old                                    1
>  699.384670258 = 750.958571520  boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-154-generic             2
>    6.003189087 = 6.445875200    boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-77-generic               5
>    6.352848053 = 6.821318656    boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-81-generic               2
>  699.384670258 = 750.958571520  initrd.img                                     2
>    6.352848053 = 6.821318656    initrd.img.old                                 2
>
> ===================== sda4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12808 Feb 24 19:47 10_linux
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 Feb 24 19:47 20_linux_xen
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Feb 24 19:47 30_os-prober
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Feb 24 19:47 30_uefi-firmware
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Feb 24 19:47 40_custom
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Feb 24 19:47 41_custom
>
> ====================== sdb/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =======================
>
> Try Ubuntu without installing
> Install Ubuntu
> OEM install (for manufacturers)
> Check disc for defects
>
> ==================== sdb: Location of files loaded by Grub =====================
>
>            GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
>             ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
>
>
> ======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================
>
> Unknown BootLoader on sdb
>
> 00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
> 00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
> 00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
> 00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
> 00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
> 00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
> 00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
> 00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
> 00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
> 00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
> 000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
> 000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
> 000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
> 000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
> 000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
> 000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
> 00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
> 00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
> 00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
> 00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
> 00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
> 00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
> *
> 000001b0  dc 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  9d 7a 03 6e 00 00 80 00  |.........z.n....|
> 000001c0  01 00 00 7e e0 fd 00 00  00 00 40 60 3f 00 00 fe  |...~......@`?...|
> 000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff ec 2e  00 00 40 13 00 00 00 00  |..........@.....|
> 000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
> 000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
> 00000200
>
>
> =============================== StdErr Messages ================================
>
> File descriptor 63 (pipe:[103038]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 24939: /bin/bash
>
> Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________
>
> The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
> sda4,
> using the following options:        sda1/boot/efi,
> Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-backups  
>
> Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________
>
>
> Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS entry (sda1/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
> ```

Comment: Looks like whatever you did, you changed the UUID of your root.  All the old UUIDs (...37e1) in /boot/grub/grub.cfg and /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg are now invalid. Edit the grub.cfg files and replace the old/invalid UUID with the current one (...611a, or just use /dev/sda4 instead of a UUID). Update-grub at first boot to rewrite the /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention that I already edited grub.cfg (In the GRUB menu, pressing 'e' and replacing all instances of the UUID ...37e1 with /dev/sda4) but the problem remained.
I will try the UUID d7851347-5b99-4bb5-adf9-47c49f33611a you mentioned, I did not see it before when looking through the log.

Comment: I tried to replace the UUID with the one you suggested but it didn't help. I've edited the post and put some links in this and the next comment, because I'm not allowed to put that many links in my posts yet.
[GRUB menu, default UUID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGbGm.jpg)  
[GRUB command line, partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGFU0.jpg)

Comment: [GRUB menu, changed UUID to d7851347-5b99-4bb5-adf9-47c49f33611a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXsWF.jpg)
[First error message, changed UUID to d7851347-5b99-4bb5-adf9-47c49f33611a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhPYZ.jpg)
[Second error message, changed UUID to d7851347-5b99-4bb5-adf9-47c49f33611a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy6Qn.jpg)

Comment: [GRUB menu replaced UUID with partition /dev/sda4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s2J3.jpg)
[First error message, replaced UUID with partition /dev/sda4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVm66.jpg)
[Second error message, replaced UUID with partition /dev/sda4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1are.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, got confused by the format break and the ...611a is a PARTUUID, not a filesystem UUID.  Try sudo blkid and post the text into your original posting.  Without the sudo, an "old" set if information may be listed. Also, the /dev/sda4-ro on the "linux" line should not have the "-ro" on it.  Otherwise that might have worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm out of office for 3 weeks now but I'll try it as soon as I am back. Thank you for your suggestions! :)

Comment: Hey, I'm back :)
Removing the "ro" did not help either and the results from "sudo blkid" can be seen in my original post under *Edit 3*.

Comment: Impatience got the best of me, I secured most data using the boot stick and reinstalled Ubuntu. Now it works properly.