# How to fix initramfs in Ubuntu?

Tags: startup, initramfs

how to fix this boot error?

[image: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol AE_NOT_FOUND Firmware bug: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; is /dev) ALERT: UUID does not exist. Dropping to a shell! BusyBox v1.30 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-6ubuntu3.1) built-in shell (ssh) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.]

I use `blkid` which returns me nothing. I searched some solutions in Google, nothing appeared except `blkid`. Can you please help me out?

Comment: I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001351/uuid-xxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)
and my operating system worked. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001351/uuid-xxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)