# uuid=xxxx does not exist

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, fstab, uuid

I have installed ubuntu22.04 and window11 double systems on my ROG zephyrus 16. Two systems work quite well previously but today when I switched from window to ubuntu, I found that it gave me an error.

```
ALERT! UUID=xxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

I can still boot window11 but can't boot ubuntu anymore.

Then I boot the ubuntu using a usb drive and tried to repair the system.

Here's the basic information about my system.

```
/etc/fstab
overlay / overlay rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0

lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS 
loop0         7:0    0     3G  1 loop /rofs
loop1         7:1    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop2         7:2    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop3         7:3    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858
loop4         7:4    0 237.2M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2987
loop5         7:5    0 485.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop6         7:6    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop7         7:7    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop8         7:8    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop9         7:9    0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
loop10        7:10   0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
sda           8:0    1 976.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1   4.7G  0 part /cdrom
├─sda2        8:2    1   4.9M  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    1   300K  0 part 
└─sda4        8:4    1 971.9G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 326.4G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   400G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  1000M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0    26G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0   260M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p8 259:8    0   200G  0 part 

blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="SYSTEM" LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="EA76-D548" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="8d47e9c8-f04f-4ae9-9cb1-7dfbd376a892" 
/dev/nvme0n1p3: TYPE="BitLocker" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="019f745a-044b-40f7-b9bc-869edc7b36de"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: TYPE="BitLocker" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="a9d76519-2dec-41d6-adb1-22d8615b900b"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="RECOVERY" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="64F2787FF27856F0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="d7ef27ca-4854-4043-a1cf-183a41987680"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: LABEL="RESTORE" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="9C76CEA776CE818E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="fc6512bb-1f3a-4cfe-b2df-8240262ede08"
/dev/nvme0n1p7: LABEL="MYASUS" UUID="0ACE-8FB3" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="9f623e03-ed78-49c1-ba08-193de1ced666"
/dev/nvme0n1p8: UUID="d1056506-5375-446d-8382-f954e74b9c67" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d311101c-9ca5-4402-9613-5059c0d346de"
/dev/sda1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2023-08-08-01-19-05-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PARTLABEL="ISO9660" PARTUUID="f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876e-c8245af921e0"

etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update 
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I used this method.

> Repair `ERROR: resume: hibernation device 'UUID: xxx' not found` This error can occur when the UUID in `/etc/fstab` does not match the actual UUID. Use `lsblk` to check the device's UUID then correct the information in `/ect/fstab`. Then open `/etc/default/grub` and change this line:

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet apparmor=1 security=apparmor resume=UUID=<correct_UUID> udev.log_priority=3"
```

> Don't forget to update grub after modification:

```bash
sudo update-grub
```

My fstab does not contain UUID so I add it to the file. Then I want to change /etc/default/grub and update it. But when I run sudo update-grub. It gave me an error

```
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow
```

I tried another method, trying to use boot-repair to repair my ubuntu boot. But it can't work as well. Does someone know what's wrong with it and help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001351/uuid-xxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)

Comment: I don't know how to change the fstab according to my situation and how to make the change work