# SGX disabled by BIOS (Acer laptop)

Tags: boot, bios, initramfs, sgx

I have an Acer laptop where I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.
After some weeks I have the following message:

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=some-string does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I have tried many workarounds found on the internet, but nothing has worked..
I.e. in my BIOS settings I can't find anything relevant about AHCI configuration.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Press F2 on init,
Go to Main section,
Find sata settings and change for AHCI.

After a long time searching, i found this solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, my BIOS didn’t have that option, after all my tries failed, I finally passed a clean copy on my Ubuntu.. Again, thank you for your interest!

Comment: I had to click CTRL + S to enable this option, you can try and check too! =D

Comment: I will! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem, I found a solution here:

https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/662587/an517-54-7159-cant-change-sata-mode

At BIOS, in Main tab, you have to press Ctrl+S to show the option, so you can change to AHCI.

It worked for me!