# "initramfs" error on boot ONLY on Dell XPS 13 (boots fine on other computer)

Tags: dell, bios, initramfs, nvme

Been struggling with this for a few days now. I am an absolutely green and non-technical Ubuntu user (I like it for it's lightweight/malware-free nature).

I repaired a hinge in the laptop that necessitated disconnecting the laptop from the battery on the motherboard. Potentially that changed some of my BIOS settings?

When I put the drive back into the computer, I began receiving an `initramfs` error on boot.

If I type `exit`, I get:

```
ALERT! UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

I've tried several fixes from around the web to no avail.

Very weirdly, I swapped the HDD into another computer (it's an NVMe drive - so a little M.2 drive) and it booted up to my usual Ubuntu desktop/account/etc. without any issue. This makes me think there isn't really any issue with my `fstab` (which I don't actually know how to edit/can't access without swapping the drive into another computer), nor any kind of disk error. I'm willing to try [chrisccoulson's solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=813090&p=5080524#post5080524) from [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=813090) if any of you think it would help.

Regardless, I can't boot on the Dell. I just get the `initramfs`/`busybox` error.

I've tried the following (swapping `sda1` for my Linux partition, of course):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
reboot
```

No luck.

As additional information (in case it's useful):

- The computer appears to recognize the NVMe hard drive as a bootable device.
- However, the NVMe drive is totally non-visible/not recognized if I boot to a live disk. I cannot edit the drive from this XPS laptop, even from a live USB disk. To edit the disk, I have to move it to another machine and then boot live.
- My thought was to just re-install Ubuntu, but, again, the NVMe drive doesn't show up as an available drive.

When I boot straight from the NVMe on the laptop, I do get the UBUNTU splash screen. So the computer definitely recognizes the NVMe as a bootable drive.

Why wouldn't I be able to see it from a live disk?

This is what makes me think some kind of BIOS change has occurred that's causing havoc.

I do believe the BIOS is the most up-to-date version (updated it a few weeks ago). I restored the BIOS to default settings just in case that might help, but no dice. I checked through the available BIOS tweaks, but can't see what among them could possibly be causing this.

Something to do with RAM settings? Or maybe I need to reseat the RAM? I don't think so, since I can boot to a live disk. Seems the NVMe drive isn't getting along with Ubuntu.

Another reason I don't think there's actually an `fstab` issue: I made no change to the data on the drive. I didn't run any updates, nada. I just disassembled some hardware that caused the CMOS to clear/reset. Hence my thinking this has something to do with a bios setting.

I could definitely use some help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28):

Problem was indeed in the BIOS settings. After entering the BIOS, I went to *System Configuration* → *SATA Operation* and changed *RAID* to *AHCI*.

Bingo.

Comment: That's it!! Thank you! Worked for me with a Dell Latitude 5491.

Comment: Same issue on the 5490 as well.

Comment: Same issue and fix for a 2020 xps

Comment: Same issue and fix for 2020 xps 9300. Possibly caused by shutting/opening laptop somehow briefly disconnecting something

Comment: Worked on a Dell XPS 13 7390, running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Apparently it switched to RAID upon very low power, by itself (well there was a yellow, Support Assist warning screen I had to click "Continue" through, but still). Running Ubuntu from a flash drive on the machine didn't even show any other drives on it so I was really worried but this fixed everything perfectly.

Comment: Worked on a Dell Latitude 7400. Thank you so much.

Comment: Okay but how do you get windows running?