# BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands. (initramfs)

Tags: 20.04

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Is this output when booting, or a comment from a script, or just a markov chain that got insanely close to creating part of a question but missed the punctuation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)