# old windows server wont boot new ubuntu installation: Gave up waiting for root file system device

Tags: boot, grub2, acpi, initramfs, busybox

I got an old server running windows server 2003 with three 1tb disk drives. The drives have been replaced and the server was used until 2018. After receiving it I wanted to wipe it so I tried to put ubuntu 20.04 on it and the test worked on the USB drive but when I installed it, it won't boot and has just given me this error:

```
[0.315524] ACPI BIOS Error (bug) : AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field (CPB3] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20210730/dsopcode-19
[0.315582] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20210730/psparse-529)

Gave up waiting for root file system device.
Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; 1s /dev)
ALERT! UUID=dBed5fc2-75f7-4d34-957b-69ec35bb709c does not exist. Dropping to a shell!


BusyBox V1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntuB) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.


(initramfs)
```

I have tried reinstalling ubuntu and changing the sata mode to ahci in the bios which was the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu), but it hasn't worked, and now we don't seem to have any accessible os. Which makes it difficult to work on.

There used to be several more errors pertaining to my floppy disc drive (yes I have one) but disabling it in the bios didn't fix it, we just disconnected it from the motherboard and that fixed them. (I don't know if this is important, thought I ought to add it just in case.)

Side note we've tried the reboot cmd in the initramfs but it didn't do anything. So we've just manually rebooted it each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a few weeks of searching I came across something called the "intel configuration utility" which is used to configure raid arrays and a few other things, it can be accessed by changing the sata mode to raid and rebooting a screen that says "press crtl-i to access the configuration utility", I used that to delete the raid array entirely which did wipe all of the data on the drives but I was going to do that anyway so that was fine.  this was the solution to the question I asked above but this is not however the end of my journey, a link to my new question is: [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433481/mtd-device-must-be-supplied-device-name-is-empty-on-old-xeon-server-you-are-i).  anyone who comes across this question should visit my new one to help me in my quest for ubuntu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).