# mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty) on old xeon server, You are in emergency mode

Tags: boot, kernel, fstab, acpi, systemd-journald

I got an old server running windows server 2003 with a xeon x3380 and three 1tb disk drives. The drives have been replaced and the server was used until 2018. After receiving it I wanted to wipe it so I tried to put ubuntu 20.04 on it and the test worked on the USB drive but when I installed it, it won't boot and is just giving me this error:

```
/dev/sdb3: clean, 173558/15237120 files, 3883372/60916992 blocks
6.654229] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
you are in emergency mode. after logging in, type "journalct1-Xb" to view 
system logs, "systemct1 reboot" to reboot, "systemct1 default" or “exit" 
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue) :
```

I have tried using fsck on the root partition but that just reported that there were no errors and I have looked through the journal as the error suggested and most of it was not too useful but I found a few portions of interest

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CPB3] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target buffer (64 bits) (20210730/dsopcode-198)
kernel:
kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_OSC]
kernel:
kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_SC]: (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
kernel: Argo: (____ptrval____) <Obj>           Buffer (16) 6E BO 11 08 27 4A F9 44
kernel: Arg1: (____ptrval____) <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
kernel: Arg2: (____ptrval____) <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
kernel: Arg3: (____ptrval____) <Obj>           Buffer (8) 01 00 00 00 9F 30 24 00
kernel:
kernel: API Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT)
```

```
kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

```
systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/mapper/isw_ceihjbhji_OS-Mirror2.
...
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
...
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
...
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/mapper/isw_ceihjbhji_OS-Mirror2.
```

before these errors there were a few pertaining to my floppy disk and raid array, refer to this question: [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427624/old-windows-server-wont-boot-new-ubuntu-installation-gave-up-waiting-for-root-f) to find out how I solved them just in case that is relevant

I have made an attempt at editing the etc/fstab file but I do not understand it and will need some extra guidance if that is to a be a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the sata mode in the bios to ide instead of ahci ended up being the solution so I’m guessing that one of my components doesn’t support ahci