# Cannot set SATA operation to AHCI

Tags: boot

After the recent BIOS update I'm not able to start Ubuntu. I found the solution to this problem here: [Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu#comment2587590_1157394)

Apparently after the update the SATA operation changed from AHCI to RAID on. I tried to switch back to AHCI, but every time I exit the BIOS it resets this option to RAID on.

I thought that maybe motherboard battery is too old, but other option are saved correctly after change.

My laptop is Dell xps 15 9500.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? My Dell with 11th Gen Intel did not even have ACHI mode. I forgot to go into UEFI to change it and Ubuntu 22.04 still  installed but used Intel® VMD driver (same as Windows 11 driver?). System only has NVMe drive. Driver list shows both vmd, ahci. Not sure Ubuntu include vmd driver in kernel with older versions.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 23.04. I tried also to install fresh Ubuntu from flash drive (thank God I have a backup), but it's telling me to first change SATA Operation.